# Highest Efficiency/Lowest resulting heat from a DC/DC conversion

Tags: power, dc, dc-dc-converter, temperature, efficiency

I have a 336VDC power source - it's a pretty unique piece of kit and won't be changing it. I'm looking to power around 500W of equipment from it at 48VDC.

However, I'm looking to do this using a DC/DC converter in an ip68 rated enclosure underground. Space in the enclosure is quite limited and obviously there is no airflow since it's waterproof etc. I'm wondering what would be the best/most efficient way of down converting this 336VDC.

So far, I've tried some off the shelf down converters rated for this voltage level which just keep overheating even in an open air environment... Beginning to wonder if this is even possible. Open to all and any suggestions

Comment: Since 336/sqrt(2) is approximately 240V, have you just considered a mains AC power supply which is fed with the DC?

Comment: How many watts (amps) on the 48v load?  How much does the load change on the 48vdc supply?  How big is the IP68 enclosure?  What is the enclosure made of?  What is the "underground" environment like (sandy, wet, sewer pipe, ...)?  What is the average temp in this "underground" area and are there any restrictions and max temp issues with other components in the enclosure besides the dc/dc converter?

Comment: @Justme no - it's an actual 336VDC source and not associated with mains AC.

About 10A thereabouts - the enclosure is made of ABS plastic and dimensions:

Height 316 mm | 9.6 in
Width 179 mm | 7.1 in
Depth 153 mm | 5.9 in

Temp is just underground manhole so probably ambient temp of 5-10 degrees year round. Wet/Sewer pipe environment.

Comment: What sort of thermal engineering have you done on this enclosure? Assume you'll need to dissipate about 50W of heat from an interior temperature of 70-80C, depending on how hot you want to run that power supply. You can use a 50W light bulb as a worst-case "stand-in" for the real supply. See how the enclosure acts, if you can't calculate it. I'd suggest getting any basic thermal engineering book, it'll have all the formulas you need to evaluate this.

Comment: "Wet/sewer pipe environment" - so the thing literally sits in air in a manhole? That enclosure can't be plastic then - due to thermal resistances involved, you'd need a rather large enclosure. Normally it'd be metal with cooling fins. Doesn't take too much to make it work. Look at cable TV/internet distribution amplifier cases: cast metal with fins. Those would work well for this. **Thermal engineering is a process**: you can't say "this is my enclosure" without doing the engineering to lead you to that enclosure. Enclosure choice is literally the **output** of the design process!!

Comment: You'll need to very carefully characterize your environment: what's the orientation, will it change?  Can you add waterproof fans or are you going to rely solely on natural convection?  How much fouling do you expect?  Baseplate cooled converters with the specs you're looking for exist - I'm looking at a few now - but they generally expect some forced airflow or liquid cooling.  You will probably need to retrofit an existing enclosure to fit a heatsink or get a custom enclosure made.  Doing the thermal legwork now will keep you from banging your head against the wall like you have been.

Answer (score 3):

Any off-the shelf switching power supply will do this job. You can power them from a DC voltage, they'll work just fine. All you need to look for then is the highest efficiency supply you can get. For galvanic protection you may wish to set it up as a -48V supply, as in telecom systems.

The power supply dissipation is the least of your concerns, though. Those 500W of power will end up powering other stuff presumably in that enclosure... You'll be dumping 550-600W of heat inside this enclosure no matter what. You'll need to do some geotechnical measurements to know the thermal resistance of whatever is at the depth you'll put the enclosure in.

You can also buy such supplies built for hermetic applications, with no air cooling, just a heat spreader plate that you'd then extract the heat from and dump it to the cooling fins outside the enclosure, coupled to surrounding rock/sediment.

Typically, for underground application, the enclosure will be metal with external fins, and with internal heat sink dumping heat to the enclosure. A fan circulating the air inside will extract the heat from internal components. The coupling with the surrounding soil/sediment/rock will be provided by a suitable thermal transfer medium - this depends a whole lot of what it's buried in.

You can dump the heat into the ground water, use liquid cooling provided from the surface, or - in absence of ground water - as long as the surrounding schmoo has enough heat capacity and low enough thermal resistance, you'd have heat-dissipating fins on the enclosure, and use some thermally conductive filler to connect the enclosure to the mineral heat sink.

> I've tried some off the shelf down converters rated for this voltage level which just keep overheating even in an open air environment

What exact part numbers have you tried, and in what conditions?

They require forced air cooling, most likely. But nobody forces you to blow this air *outside* of the enclosure. Not at all. The air will circulate *inside* the enclosure. Then it's your job to extract the heat from that air and dump it outside. How you'll do that depends on the environment the box is in. If it's literally buried, then heat conduction to the soil/rock will be one way of getting rid of the heat. If it's on the bottom of a wide enough well to support convection, dumping the heat to air outside the cabinet will work. One heat sink inside the case, another directly over it on the outside, blow air through both: inside air inside the case, outside air outside the case, done.

**Please add relevant detail to the question, as otherwise it's a lot of guesswork and can't be answered to anyone's satisfaction**.

Comment: The 500W of power will actually be delivered outside of the enclosure - so its just heat dissipation within the enclosure I need to worry about. Understood ref. the enclosure materials - am currently stuck with an ABS IP68 rated enclosure I am trying to use - do you think with a sufficient switching power supply this would be do-able?

Comment: _”You can power them from a DC voltage, they'll work just fine.”_ What do you think will happen when there is a fault and the AC rated fuse have to break 330 V DC instead?

Comment: @winny A self-imposed problem: nobody forces you to use the AC-rated fuse :) The fuse inside the supply is to protect against catastrophic failure. You still need to provide external circuit protection, with an appropriately selected fuse for the application. So that's very simple: you can choose not to have that problem :)

Comment: The fuse in the COTS supply assumes AC input and you just proposed to feed it with DC. What do you think will happen?

Comment: "What do you think will happen?"  Nothing.  With a 500 W load, the average current at 336 Vdc will be 25% less than the RMS current at 240 Vac.  The fuse element will be under more stress with an AC source.  Or, the AC source current will be 33% more than the DC source current.

Comment: **"Any off-the shelf switching power supply will do this job." ** Got to disagree. The vast majority are designed for air cooling only, and operate at around 80% efficiency. That's 120 watts of heat to remove, but with no external air source.  Without at least a metal panel somewhere in the plastic box, this is a problem.

Comment: @AnalogKid No, when there is a fault inside the power supply and the AC rated fuse tries it best to break it.